# Required validator doesn't work with custom validator - Angular 5

Tags: angular, validation, custom-validators

I created a custom validator (checkHallNumber) that works but when I implement it with required validator there is a problem: When I click on the empty input field and then out of it, it doesnt show the error message and the form is valid. But when I use only the required validator it works fine. Also, only when the custom validator acts then the required validator works.

[HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKmex.png)

[TS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFc6j.png)

[An error that disappears after I click something in the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM6ax.png)

[Part of a service responsible for thw validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7KXX.png)

What can I do to fix it ?
Thank you !

Comment: show admin.service file

Comment: I posted the relevant part of the service file

Comment: this.thaterArr is undefined. That is causing the error.

Comment: Thank you ! I initiated thaterArr with an empty array and it worked :)